# Open Source Tokenizer

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an open source annotation processor for Android ([ngAndroid](https://github.com/davityle/ngAndroid)). Part of the library is a small Java subset compiled language that can be used for data binding, events, etc. I plan to extend the functionality of this language but my Tokenizer is getting out of hand.

The Tokenizer parses strings such as `getTimeString(note.time)`, 
`modelName.boolValue ? functionName(m.parameter , q.secondParameter  ) : modelName.stringValue`, `(3 + (2)) - 10/5` etc.

```
public class Tokenizer {

    private enum State{
        BEGIN,
        END,
        MODEL_PERIOD,
        FUNCTION_PARAMETER_START,
        CLOSE_PARENTHESIS,
        TERNARY_QUESTION,
        TERNARY_COLON,
        STRING_START,
        STRING_END,
        IN_STRING,
        IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT,
        KNOT_EQUALS,
        EQUALS_START,
        FUNCTION_PARAMETER_DELIMINATOR,
        EQUALS,
        KNOT_EQUALS_START,
        MODEL_NAME_END,
        MODEL_FIELD_END,
        FUNCTION_NAME_END,
        NUMBER_CONSTANT_END,
        IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE,
        IN_MODEL_FIELD,
        KNOT_VALUE,
        OPERATOR,
        IN_FLOAT,
        FLOAT_END,
        DOUBLE_END,
        INTEGER_END,
        LONG_END,
        NESTED_EXPRESSION,
        IN_STRING_SLASH,
        STRING_SLASH_END,
        WHITESPACE, FLOAT_F_END
    }

    private int index, readIndex;
    private String script;
    private Queue<Token> tokens;
    private State state;

    public Tokenizer(String script) {
        this.script = script;
    }

    public Queue<Token> getTokens() {
        if (tokens == null) {
            generateTokens();
        }
        return tokens;
    }

    private void generateTokens() {
        tokens = new LinkedList<Token>();
        index = 0;
        readIndex = 0;

        state = State.BEGIN;
        while (state != State.END) {
            state = nextState();
        }
        if (readIndex != script.length()) {
            emit(TokenType.RUBBISH);
        }

        tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.EOF, null));
    }

    private State nextState() {
        State result;
        switch (state){
            case BEGIN:
            case EQUALS_START:
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case IN_STRING:
                if(peek() == '\\'){
                    result = State.IN_STRING_SLASH;
                }else
                    result = getNextState();
                break;
            case IN_STRING_SLASH:
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case STRING_SLASH_END:
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE: {
                char c = peek();
                switch (c) {
                    case '.':
                        result = State.MODEL_NAME_END;
                        break;
                    case '(':
                        result = State.FUNCTION_NAME_END;
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = getNextState();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case END:
                result = State.END;
                break;
            case MODEL_NAME_END:
                emit(TokenType.MODEL_NAME);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case FUNCTION_NAME_END:
                emit(TokenType.FUNCTION_NAME);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case MODEL_PERIOD:
                emit(TokenType.PERIOD);
                result = State.IN_MODEL_FIELD;
                break;
            case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_START:
                emit(TokenType.OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case CLOSE_PARENTHESIS:
                emit(TokenType.CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case TERNARY_QUESTION:
                emit(TokenType.TERNARY_QUESTION_MARK);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case TERNARY_COLON:
                emit(TokenType.TERNARY_COLON);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case STRING_START:
                result = State.IN_STRING;
                break;
            case STRING_END:
                emit(TokenType.STRING);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case IN_FLOAT: {
                if (!Character.isDigit(peek())){
                    result = State.FLOAT_END;
                }else
                    result = getNextState();
                break;
            }
            case IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT: {
                char c = peek();
                if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != '.')
                    result = State.NUMBER_CONSTANT_END;
                else
                    result = getNextState();
                break;
            }
            case FLOAT_END: {
                char c = peek();
                if (c != 'd' && c != 'D' && c != 'f' && c != 'F')
                    emit(TokenType.FLOAT_CONSTANT);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            }
            case NUMBER_CONSTANT_END: {
                char c = peek();
                if (c != 'l' && c != 'L' && c != 'f' && c != 'F' && c != 'd' && c != 'D')
                    emit(TokenType.INTEGER_CONSTANT);

                result = getNextState();
                break;
            }
            case FLOAT_F_END:
                emit(TokenType.FLOAT_CONSTANT);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case DOUBLE_END:
                emit(TokenType.DOUBLE_CONSTANT);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case LONG_END:
                emit(TokenType.LONG_CONSTANT);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_DELIMINATOR:
                emit(TokenType.COMMA);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case IN_MODEL_FIELD: {
                char c = peek();
                if (c != '_' && !Character.isLetter(c)) {
                    result = State.MODEL_FIELD_END;
                } else {
                    result = getNextState();
                }
                break;
            }
            case NESTED_EXPRESSION:
                emit(TokenType.OPEN_PARENTHESIS_EXP);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case KNOT_EQUALS_START:
                if(peek() != '='){
                    result = State.KNOT_VALUE;
                }else{
                    result = getNextState();
                }
                break;
            case KNOT_VALUE:
                emit(TokenType.KNOT);
                result = State.IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE;
                break;
            case MODEL_FIELD_END:
                emit(TokenType.MODEL_FIELD);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case KNOT_EQUALS:
            case EQUALS:
            case OPERATOR:
                emit(TokenType.BINARY_OPERATOR);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            case WHITESPACE:
                emit(TokenType.WHITESPACE);
                result = getNextState();
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("This shouldn't happen. Please submit an issue at github.com/davityle/ngAndroid/issues");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void advance() {
        index++;
    }

    private State getNextState() {
        try {
            if (index >= script.length()) {
                return State.END;
            }

            if(state == State.IN_STRING_SLASH) {
                script = script.substring(0, index) + script.substring(index + 1, script.length());
                index--;
                return State.STRING_SLASH_END;
            }
            if(state == State.STRING_SLASH_END) {
                return State.IN_STRING;
            }

            char currentCharacter = script.charAt(index);

            if(state == State.IN_STRING && currentCharacter != '\'')
                return state;

            if(state == State.IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT && currentCharacter == '.'){
                return State.IN_FLOAT;
            }

            if (Character.isDigit(currentCharacter)) {
                switch (state){
                    case IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE:
                        return State.IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE;
                    case IN_FLOAT:
                        return State.IN_FLOAT;
                    case IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT:
                    case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_START:
                    case OPERATOR:
                    case BEGIN:
                    case TERNARY_QUESTION:
                    case TERNARY_COLON:
                    case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_DELIMINATOR:
                    case EQUALS:
                    case KNOT_EQUALS:
                    case WHITESPACE:
                    case NESTED_EXPRESSION:
                        return State.IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT;
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid character '" + currentCharacter + "' at state " + state.toString());
                }
            }

            if (Character.isLetter(currentCharacter)) {
                switch (state) {
                    case IN_MODEL_FIELD:
                    case IN_STRING:
                    case MODEL_NAME_END:
                    case FUNCTION_NAME_END:
                    case MODEL_FIELD_END:
                        return state;
                    case BEGIN:
                    case IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE:
                    case TERNARY_QUESTION:
                    case TERNARY_COLON:
                    case OPERATOR:
                    case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_START:
                    case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_DELIMINATOR:
                    case EQUALS:
                    case NESTED_EXPRESSION:
                    case KNOT_EQUALS:
                    case WHITESPACE:
                        return State.IN_CHAR_SEQUENCE;
                    case KNOT_EQUALS_START:
                        return State.KNOT_VALUE;
                    case NUMBER_CONSTANT_END:
                        if(currentCharacter == 'l' || currentCharacter == 'L')
                            return State.LONG_END;
                    case FLOAT_END:
                        if(currentCharacter == 'd' || currentCharacter == 'D')
                            return State.DOUBLE_END;
                        if(currentCharacter == 'f' || currentCharacter == 'F')
                            return State.FLOAT_F_END;
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid character '" + currentCharacter + "' at state " + state.toString());
                }
            }

            switch (currentCharacter) {
                case ',':
                    return State.FUNCTION_PARAMETER_DELIMINATOR;
                case '.':
                    return state == State.IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT ? State.IN_NUMBER_CONSTANT : State.MODEL_PERIOD;
                case '(':
                    return state == State.FUNCTION_NAME_END ? State.FUNCTION_PARAMETER_START : State.NESTED_EXPRESSION;
                case ')':
                    return State.CLOSE_PARENTHESIS;
                case '?':
                    return State.TERNARY_QUESTION;
                case ':':
                    return State.TERNARY_COLON;
                case '\'':
                    return state == State.IN_STRING ? State.STRING_END : State.STRING_START;
                case '!':
                    return State.KNOT_EQUALS_START;
                case '=':
                    return state == State.KNOT_EQUALS_START ? State.KNOT_EQUALS : state == State.EQUALS_START ? State.EQUALS : State.EQUALS_START;
                case '*':
                case '+':
                case '-':
                case '/':
                    return State.OPERATOR;
                case '_':{
                    if(state == State.IN_MODEL_FIELD)
                        return state;
                }

            }

            if(Character.isWhitespace(currentCharacter)){
                return State.WHITESPACE;
            }

            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid character : " + currentCharacter + " in state " + state);
        }finally {
            advance();
        }
    }

    private char peek() {
        return index < script.length() ? script.charAt(index) : 0;
    }

    private void emit(TokenType tokenType) {
        if(tokenType != TokenType.WHITESPACE) {
            Token token = new Token(tokenType, script.substring(readIndex, index));
            tokens.add(token);
        }
        readIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can improve it?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

> ```
> c != 'l' && c != 'L' && c != 'f' && c != 'F' && c != 'd' && c != 'D'
> ```

I would write:

```
"lLfFdD".indexOf(c) == -1
```

---

In the many `case` statements, instead of storing the result in the `result` variable, and then returning it in the end, how about returning earlier, as soon as the value to return is ready? This way the code can become shorter, as you won't need the `break` statements anymore.

---

It's recommended to use braces with even single line `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

For your `switch (state)`, you seem to have a lot of cases where they are just doing:

```
    case VALUE:
        emit(TokenType.MAPPED_VALUE);
        result = getNextState();
        break;
```

You can consider making the `TokenType` value an instance field of the `State` enums to perform the mapping, so that you can coalesce the cases:

```
// inside State enum
private static TokenType getTokenValue() {
    // this can be initialized to null, or set via constructor
    return tokenValue;
}

// inside getNextState()
    case MODEL_NAME_END:
    case FUNCTION_NAME_END:
        emit(state.getTokenValue());
        return getNextState();
    case MODEL_PERIOD:
        emit(TokenType.PERIOD);
        return State.IN_MODEL_FIELD;
    case FUNCTION_PARAMETER_START:
    case CLOSE_PARENTHESIS:
    case TERNARY_QUESTION:
        emit(state.getTokenValue());
        return getNextState();
```

Note that I am also `return`-ing immediately from each case, rather than saving into a `result` field.